# How can I reinstall eOS 5.1.7?

Tags: software-installation

how can I reinstall eOS 5.1.7? Now I have this OS, but due to some reasons I can't install any application.  Therefore I want to reinstall eOS.

`sudo apt install --reinstall elementary-desktop` DOES NOT HELP.
Thanks

Comment: The same way you already installed it. Either burn the .ISO to disk or use something like Balena Etcher to write the .ISO to USB. Then, reboot and pick the USB/DVD as your boot device. Choose the 'erase disk' option during the installation, which will remove the current install and install it again.

Comment: Thanks, I did it, it`s OK now